# Run SWT based GUI in OSGi Framework

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, osgi, bundle

I am following a simple [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SWT/article.html) on SWT. It works fine when I run it as a Java application. How do I make it to run it as an OSGi bundle? Are there any special configuration settings to be done?

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might as well build your GUI as an [Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform) (RCP) GUI.

That way, Eclipse will manage the OSGI code, and you can concentrate on the SWT or JFace code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at bnd(tools). The only special thing for SWT is that the Display event loop is on the main thread on a Mac. The bndtools launcher has special support for this. Whereever you want to run the Display event loop, register a Runnable service with a main.thread=true service property. This Runnable is then called on the main thread.

For the rest it is just normal plain old OSGi ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Activator class implement `BundleActivator` (osgi) and Create Display, open Shell(window) and run SWT event loop in  `start(BundleContext context)`  and dispose  Display, Shell in `stop(BundleContext context)`.